# Quarkus default coroutines context

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, quarkus, resteasy, coroutine

Is it possible to change the default coroutine context for `suspend`able HTTP methods managed by RestEasy ?

I need to add an additional, custom `CouroutineContext.Element` to every Resource method, but doing `withContext` everywhere is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: It is not. Please open a new issue on our GitHub repo asking for the feature while also providing an example use case if possible.